# local variable "hit" referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I got this error i don't know why with an another dataset it works.

I trying to compute a metrics for a recommender

```
def _verify_hit_top_n(anime_id, recommended_anime, topn):        
try:
    index = next(i for i, c in enumerate(recommended_anime) if c == anime_id)
except:
    index = -1
    hit = int(index in range(0, topn))
return hit, index

for anime_id in user_anime_watched_testset : 
            hit_at_3, index_at_3 = _verify_hit_top_n(anime_id, valid_recs, 3)
            hits_at_3_count += hit_at_3            
            anime_metrics = {'hits@3_count':hits_at_3_count}
```

---

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-99d14e064672> in <module>()
      1 for anime_id in user_anime_watched_testset :
----> 2             hit_at_3, index_at_3 = _verify_hit_top_n(anime_id, valid_recs, 3)
      3             hits_at_3_count += hit_at_3
      4             anime_metrics = {'hits@3_count':hits_at_3_count}

<ipython-input-102-844edc58db79> in _verify_hit_top_n(anime_id, recommended_anime, topn)
     16     except:
     17         index = -1
---> 18     return hit, index
     19 
     20 for anime_id in user_anime_watched_testset:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hit' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Well, what happens if your code doesn't throw an exception and never enters the `except` block?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not getting an exception so it's never reaching the Except block. This causes the fact that your `hit = int(index in range(0, topn))` line is actually never called, so the variable is indeed referenced before assigning

Comment: I tried to put hit in the "try" block but it did'nt change anything

Answer (score 0):

You are returning variable hit, but `hit` gets assigned in except block.  Your code is not entering in except block and hit never gets assigned